# Printing Selected Row in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, printing, selected

Is there a way to print only the information from selected rows in a GridView? I know how to print an ENTIRE GridView, by giving its div an ID...but I can't seem to figure out how I could extract just the information from each selected row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you can do this by adding a style to row the user has selected (ie class="printMe"). Your print style sheet can have a style with display none for all the rows in the gridview, except for the style which you have added to the row.

```
#MyGrid TR {display:none;}
#MyGrid TR.printMe {display:block; }
```